# How to create select options dropdown based countryName and load state from two extranal json file in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json

First Select country options loading from extranal json file and second select state option loading from another json file based first select countryName option i need to show relevant states second select state option in angularJs. I tried bellow code.

```
index.html
---
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   tab.html // here tab.html injected here based routing
</div>
tab.html
---------
tab1
-----

<div ng-controller="tabCtrl">
       <div ng-include="'registration.html'"></div>
    </div>

registration.html
---------------
<div ng-controller="regCtrl">
<select id="country" style="width:250px;" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"><option value='' selected>Select</option></select>
    <select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states"><option value=''>Select</option></select></div>

</div>
script
-----
$http.get('assets/countryName.json').then(function(data) {debugger;
        $scope.countries= data;
});
$http.get('assets/stateNames.json').then(function(data) {debugger;
        $scope.states= data;
});

countryName.json
----------------
{
  "IN": ["India"],
   "ZA": ["South Africa"],
    "AT": ["Austria"]
}


StateName.json
 --------------
{
"IN":[
       "Delhi",
      "Goa",
      "Gujarat",
      "Himachal Pradesh",
]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since states is the object, whenever user select country from dropdown, state1 will update.state1 will contain key of city.

```
 <div><select id="country" style="width:250px;" class="" name="selectFranchise" ng-model="state1">
<option value="">Select</option>
  <option ng-repeat="(key,country) in countries"  value="{{key}}">{{country[0]}}</option>
   </select></div>

<div><select id="state" ng-model="cities"><option value=''>Select</option>
  <option ng-repeat="city in states[state1]" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option></select></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankitg1602/Lc3n55d2/#)

Comment: I tried you code not coming coutnry names in dropdown and also state on loading time

Comment: only conuntry key displaying values not displaying , country selection options like IN,ZA,AT

Comment: I tried second approch  drop down showing {{country}} and error in console showing:Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$compile/ctreq?p0=select&p1=ngOptions
    (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js:58:157)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js:58:157)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js:58:157) <div ng-include="'views/registration.html'" class="ng-scope">

Comment: please help me. when we using second approach only I am getting this error

Comment: please share your complete code.I will solve the problem

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:iidexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngRepeat/iidexp?p0=countryNaNor%20(country%2C%20key)

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:iidexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngRepeat/iidexp?p0=stateNaNor%20(state%2Ccity) second error

Comment: i selected india also state options is not coming

Comment: till not coming states

Comment: $scope.states object coming in controller but in browser not displaying

Comment: @sitabane click on jsfiddle,I shared working code with you

Comment: please help me to make default select as US in your code@ankit guta

Comment: here i update your jsfidde to making INDIA as default select https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/6/

Comment: Not getting what exactly do you want @sitabane

Comment: now select country drop down is coming in that i need make default select as india

Comment: By default is "India" need be select , how we can do your code

Comment: please show once your jsfiddle , INDIA as default selector